# Is BitTorrent Sync a spyware?

Tags: spyware, torrent, bittorrent

Source: http://www.infoworld.com/t/development-tools/bittorrent-sync-gaining-major-traction-peer-peer-alternative-dropbox-232144

> and the average usage has hit 20GB per person.

How can they know that without using some sort of spyware to monitor and keep track on a central server somewhere?  If it's P2P, they would never be able to figure out that average usage is 20GB per person. Am I right?

Comment: They could measure the average on the P2P client and send the value to their central server in large intervals. Check the privacy policy.

Comment: Note that measuring data _volume_ is not the same thing as having access to it: with correctly used strong crypto, a third party could still see that 20 GB are stored, but won't have a clue what the data _is_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BitTorrent Sync [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync&hl=en) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bittorrent-sync/id665156116?mt=8) apps seem to follow the [BitTorrent.com privacy policy](http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/privacy) which states explicitly that they gather data such as total traffic and performance metrics.

> We also aggregate some data from the BitTorrent Client regarding total
>   traffic flows and content delivery performance.

I don't see any problem with that; it's completely understandable. This data can be useful to them when further developing the protocol, helps them understand P2P performance in the big picture, and, perhaps, to measure their own value as a service.